# Weird memory leaking on Galaxy Nexus. Are there known issues?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, galaxy

I've run into an issue with a user of my apps on Galaxy Nexus. It is a game that is fairly graphically intensive, and essentially what occurs is that as he switches from activity to activity, the memory gradually runs out.

This is a Galaxy Nexus with (as far as I know) stock Android 4.0.2. Excerpts from the LogCat:

```
D/.GameViewActivity( 3203): debug. =================================
D/.GameViewActivity( 3203): debug.heap native: allocated 6.01MB of 8.95MB (0.04MB free) in [.GameViewActivity]
D/.GameViewActivity( 3203): debug.memory: allocated: 54.00MB of 64.00MB (14.00MB free)
D/dalvikvm( 3203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 366K, 28% free 40426K/55623K, paused 4ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm( 3203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 28% free 40425K/55623K, paused 1ms+4ms
```

A short while later (a matter of minutes), it will look like this:

```
D/.MainActivity( 3203): debug. =================================
D/.MainActivity( 3203): debug.heap native: allocated 6.92MB of 11.36MB (0.18MB free) in [.MainActivity]
D/.MainActivity( 3203): debug.memory: allocated: 58.00MB of 64.00MB (1.00MB free)
D/dalvikvm( 3203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 297K, 4% free 58119K/60359K, paused 1ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm( 3203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 4% free 58116K/60359K, paused 1ms+5ms
I/WindowManager(17943): createSurface Window{41fadf88 .MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
D/OpenGLRenderer( 3203): Flushing caches (mode 0)
I/ActivityManager(17943): Displayed .MainActivity: +556ms (total +743ms)
D/dalvikvm(17943): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 823K, 14% free 24118K/27911K, paused 86ms
D/.GameViewActivity( 3203): debug. =================================
D/.GameViewActivity( 3203): debug.heap native: allocated 6.95MB of 11.36MB (0.15MB free) in [.GameViewActivity]
D/.GameViewActivity( 3203): debug.memory: allocated: 58.00MB of 64.00MB (1.00MB free)
D/dalvikvm( 3203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 4% free 58488K/60359K, paused 2ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm( 3203): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 58487K/60359K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

Followed by a crash and out of memory.

Now, I've gotten used to Android's hopeless memory management system resulting in unavoidable crashes for my games (it's - by far - the most reported error in the Android dashboard, and it doesn't matter how rigorously I excise the memory in the app - graphics + Android memory management = force closes). I only use Android components + SurfaceView, though heavily skinned/styled with custom graphics.

The weird thing that catches my attention with this, however, is the phone.

Now - firstly - it is a Galaxy Nexus, so pretty much the most advanced phone out there at the moment, with the most available memory for its apps. It is very strange that this phone, of all those out there, should have this kind of problem.

Secondly, I have the exact same phone - also running 4.0.2 - and I use it as my primary testing phone. My user can get the game to crash literally in minutes; when I play the game, it can run for hours and will consistently have 20-25Mb of memory free.

Thirdly, this app runs on tens of thousands of phones daily, so I am 100% sure that the app does **not** have any issues that should cause this kind of catastrophic memory leak that my user is seeing.

In short - I'm stumped, completely and utterly.

Any thoughts? Has anyone here seen something like this before? Are there known issues with the Galaxy Nexus that I've not heard of? Any strategies/questions/tests I might ask this user that might help pin down the problem here?

Comment: There is always that one device that behaves unexpected :) If the user has some experience maybe he can dump you a memory profile so you you can have a look at the allocations: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html ( or you do in [code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData%28java.lang.String%29))

Comment: Submit this as an answer, and I'll accept it. Sending the user a test version that dumped a hprof at least allowed me to see what classes were blowing up on his phone (a bunch of Activity classes), although I still do not understand why this happens on his phone, but not on mine.

Comment: Something caused by different settings like timezone, language or the other system settings maybe. There is an option under Settings > Dev options that changes something about Activity management but I don't know what it does tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has some experience maybe he can dump you a memory profile so you you can have a look at the allocations.

See http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html for some  instructions.

You can also try to dump the memory profile from your app using [Debug#dumpHprofData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData%28java.lang.String%29) and ask users to send you that file.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, but dumping memory in-code at least allowed me to get an idea of what elements are blowing up on the user phone. Hopefully some more experimentation may point me to the culprit.